# How to allocate the right amount of memory (c)

Tags: c, shared-memory

I'm currently experimenting on `C`, memory allocation and shared memory. I need help, the code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

#include "shared_memory.h"
#include "semaphore.h"
#include "errExit.h"

struct Node {
    int ID;
    char password[10];
    struct Node *next;
};

key_t shmKeyServer = 131;
size_t size = (sizeof(struct Node)) * 100;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int shmidServer = alloc_shared_memory(shmKeyServer, size);
    struct Node *node = (struct Node *)get_shared_memory(shmidServer, 0);

    //fill all the structs

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
       node->ID = i;
       sprintf(node->password, "%s%i", "campo num:", i);
       node->next = node + sizeof(struct Node);
       printf("you are on %i cicle \n", i);
       node = node->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The function `alloc_shared_memory` is here:

```
int alloc_shared_memory(key_t shmKey, size_t size) {
   // get, or create, a shared memory segment
   int shmid = shmget(shmKey, size, IPC_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
   if (shmid == -1)
       errExit("shmget failed");

   return shmid;
}
```

`get_shared_memory`:

```
void *get_shared_memory(int shmid, int shmflg) {
    // attach the shared memory
    void *ptr_sh = shmat(shmid, NULL, shmflg);
    if (ptr_sh == (void *)-1)
        errExit("shmat failed");

    return ptr_sh;
}
```

The problem is that after the 8th cicle. I get segmentation error. 
I think the problem is the memory allocation or the size declaration.

Comment: And what did your debugger tell you?

Comment: At least one culprit is actually `sprintf(node->password, "%s%i", "campo num:", i)`.   `"campo num:` has length 10, so the `sprintf()` call is guaranteed to write more than 10 characters.     According to your `struct` definition, `node->password` has length of exactly 10 characters.    The behaviour is therefore undefined.   Either ensure the array is large enough, or write less characters to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line:

```
node->next = node + sizeof(struct Node);
```

As `typeof(node)` is `struct Node *` this statement increments the `node` pointer by `sizeof(struct Node) * sizeof(struct Node)` bytes (see pointer arithmetic in C). You want to increment the `node` pointer by `sizeof(struct Node)` bytes, not by `sizeof(struct Node)` nodes.

You want:

```
node->next = (char*)node + sizeof(struct Node);
// or better:
node->next = (void*)((uintptr_t)(void*)node + sizeof(struct Node));
node->next = (void*)((char*)(void*)node + sizeof(struct Node));
// or 
node->next = node + 1;
node->next = &node[1];
```

Which fixes the seg fault.

In the line:

```
sprintf(node->password, "%s%i", "campo num:", i);
```

undefined behavior happens. The `"%s%i", "campo num:", i` is printing 12 bytes into `node->password` pointer, which has only `10` bytes of memory:

```
campo num:1
```

is 11 character + 1 byte for string terminating zero byte. Also for numbers greater then `10` `sprintf` will write 13 bytes. It's best to use `snprintf` as in `snprintf(node->password, sizeof(node->password)` to protect against buffer overflows. Also you can `sprintf` return value `int ret = sprintf(..);  if (ret > sizeof(node->password)) { err(1, "Overflowed"); }`

Comment: Please use `node->next = node + 1` - it’s the most straightforward and readable.  Contrary to Kamil Cuk’s assertion, it’s not meant to confuse - adding 1 to a pointer yields the address of the next object in a sequence.  That’s how pointer arithmetic works.  All the casting gymnastics just make the code harder to read and give you more opportunities to make a mistake.